# How to make desktop or offline app from Rails background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, desktop-application, offlineapps

I've built a Rails app that is going to be in use in a location that has limited to no internet. I'm trying to decide on the best route to translate my work into something functional as quickly as possible -- whether via a desktop app or some offline version of what I have.

The app's purposes are as follows:
- Record biographical data from one-on-one personal surveys
- Export locally entered demographic datasets and import and process other similar datasets
---- Don't need to support anything too sophisticated (graphically or otherwise), just basic Rails with Backbone.js for interactive survey views

I'm just wondering about the fastest way to get something functional that can work offline given the Rails app I have (and my Rails background). Do I want something like Titanium? Google Gears? Something like Prism or Fluid? My primary concern is getting something working quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an offline app and you want to store data locally and have it synched back in a HTML5 like environment there are three solutions I know of.

- [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) - Seems firmly in the data synchronisation world as apposed to trying to do too much. The disadvantage is it is commercial and a hosted service.
- [Hood.ie](http://hood.ie/) - I dislike big frameworks and to me this seems to be attempting to do too much, I don't understand why some of the features are in there (email for example) and may be incomplete. It is open source however and  has been created by some big names in the JS scene so it certainly deserves good consideration.
- [SyncIt](http://forbesmyester.github.io/SyncIt/index.html) - Disclaimer I wrote this so I only see it's good parts and, of course think it is the best solution.  SyncIt is OSS and just does data synchronization and nothing else. It is made of very decoupled components with small API's so it should be only a day or so's work to change the Node.JS back end to be a Rails one (I don't know rails but would help such an effort). It has good test coverage and is mostly VanillaJS so should be a stable technology base for the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Local**

Why don't you just use the Rails application but with all local components?

For example, you can use `MYSQL` / `PGSQL` locally; install a `web server` locally, and then add a simple domain to your hosts file to contact

This will allow you to treat your *local* requests as production, giving you the ability to load the domain in your browser, and have it run as if you were connecting to a real website:

--

**DB**

You can [install mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) by using the following:

[image]

If you install that, just go into your `database.yml` and change the settings to your local setup:

```
#config/database.yml
production:
   ...
   host: 127.0.0.1
```

--

**Server**

Although you could run the Rails server, that will only run in `development` mode.

You'll be much better installing [`Apache` (to handle inbound requests) and `Phusion Passenger`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) to run a Rails environment

You'll be able to use [this tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3) to do this (I can provide specifics if you comment)

--

**Domain**

Finally, you'll be able to set up a domain in your `hosts` file

All you'll need to do is mask `127.0.0.1` with a domain like `Rails.app` or something, so if you go to `http://rails.app`, it will come up with your application:

```
#hosts
127.0.0.1 rails.app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tutorial from [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1) it use rack-offline

- Add gem "rack-offline"
- add to the routes `match "/application.manifest"=. Rails::Offline`
- and this will create a cache file manifest
- on the layout view add `<html manifest="/application.manifest">`
- Now you need a variabel so the assets will load on the offline app `ENV["Rails_ASSET_ID"] =""` this will disable the timestamps in the assets files add this to the application.rb config file
  Now you got the app offline still need to fix some code to make it work perfect
- Any dynamic content got to add it via js and json, need to  store the dynamic content offile 
  I use the same code in the tutorial to add the content
- jquery.tmpl
- jquery.offline
  You can look more info on that.